# TypeORM OneToOne relationship cascade delete not working

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm building a simple invoice API.

I have two classes `Invoice` and `Address`, `Invoice` has two fields related to `Address`: `senderAddress` and `clientAddress`

I want be able to delete `Invoice` and auto-remove `senderAddress` and `clientAddress`.

I tried so many things like adding the `onDelete and Cascade` to `Address OneToOne`, they wont be deleted.

```js
export class Invoice {
    @OneToOne(() => Address, (senderAddress) => senderAddress.invoice, {
        cascade: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    senderAddress: Address;

    @OneToOne(() => Address, (clientAddress) => clientAddress.invoice, {
        cascade: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    clientAddress: Address;
}
```

```js
export class Address {
    @OneToOne(() => Invoice)
    invoice: Invoice;
}
```

This is how I delete the `Invoice`

```
async remove(id: number): Promise<Invoice> {
    const invoice = await this.invoiceRepository.findOne(id);
    if (!invoice)
        throw new HttpException('Invoice not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    return await this.invoiceRepository.remove(invoice);
}
```

This is generated when generating migrations:

```js
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE \`invoices-app\`.\`invoice\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`createdAt\` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), \`paymentDue\` datetime NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`paymentTerms\` int NOT NULL, \`clientName\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`clientEmail\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`status\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`total\` int NOT NULL, \`senderAddressId\` int NULL, \`clientAddressId\` int NULL, \`userId\` int NULL, UNIQUE INDEX \`REL_39d5b5b8c9b14ee7d3a28ec6be\` (\`senderAddressId\`), UNIQUE INDEX \`REL_2d58047fd2c36422476e1e1fd3\` (\`clientAddressId\`), PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`,
        );

        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE \`invoices-app\`.\`address\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`street\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`city\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`postCode\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`country\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`,
        );

        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE \`invoices-app\`.\`invoice\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_39d5b5b8c9b14ee7d3a28ec6be3\` FOREIGN KEY (\`senderAddressId\`) REFERENCES \`invoices-app\`.\`address\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );

        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE \`invoices-app\`.\`invoice\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_2d58047fd2c36422476e1e1fd36\` FOREIGN KEY (\`clientAddressId\`) REFERENCES \`invoices-app\`.\`address\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION`,
        );
}
```

This is my entire ER Diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the inverse side as a second parameter on `senderAddress` and `clientAddress`, like so:

```js
export class Invoice {
    @OneToOne(() => Address, 
     senderAddress => senderAddress.invoice, // inverse side
     {
        cascade: ['insert'],
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    senderAddress: Address;

    @OneToOne(() => Address, 
     clientAddress => clientAddress.invoice, // inverse side
     {
        cascade: ['insert'],
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    clientAddress: Address;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir but they still being not deleted

Comment: @H3lltronik you may need to perform the database migration again - assuming you let TypeORM auto generate and modify the database using annotations.

Comment: Thank you again sir, I updated my post. I was using ```synchronize: true``` then I changed it to false and used migrations but it didn't worked either but I saw the generate code and it is adding the ```ON DELETE CASCADE``` in the constraints it should be working, right? can you please check it out?

Comment: @H3lltronik `synchronize: true` is generally great for development but a bad idea for production. Small changes like two that I posted for example may not be considered in this case so that you end up fiddling around with the database itself...

Comment: @H3lltronik the migration you created looks ok. Should be working, yes. You might want to run those queries in a transaction within your `up` method, e.g. `return queryRunner.connection.transaction(async (em: EntityManager) => Promise.all([em.query('sql 1...'), em.query('sql 2...')]));`

Comment: One more thing: I'ld keep the inverse side parameters as shown though - just for reference in your codebase.